# An issue with zenity and printf (C stdio)

Tags: c, bash, zenity

I'm trying to make a graphical utility with **bash**, **zenity** and a script written in **C** and there is an issue with progressbar, zenity ignores input from the C script.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int i=0; i < 11; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", i*10);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

A bash version of the same:

```
for (( i=0; i < 11; i++ )); do
    echo $(( i*10 ))
    sleep 1
done
```

This will give the same result in a terminal: 0,10,20..100 separated by a new line. But zenity will take it from echo and won't take it from printf. Why?

That's how I use zenity with C scripts:

```
gcc -o pp pp.c # C script from above

./pp | zenity --progress --auto-close
```

And how I use it with bash:

```
(for ((i=0; i<11; i++)); do echo $(( i*10 )); sleep 1; done) | zenity --progress --auto-close
```

I even tried to replace **echo** by **printf** in bash:

```
printf "%d\n" $(( i*10 ))
```

It also works fine.

Comment: There's probably a couple of duplicates of this question. TL;DR: You're suffering from buffering. `fflush(stdout);` after each `printf`.

Comment: @melpomene Does the new line character not force a flush?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons, it does (by default) when output is to a TTY, not when it's to a pipe.

Comment: @melpomene, thank you.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thank you too, i had no idea.